# Issue with nested array in Zapier Trigger Response

Tags: zapier, signnow

Hi I'm having issues building my Zap with SignNow. I'm trying to extract the email of the Signer from the response data, but because the Signers portion of the response data is a nested array Zapier appears to just flatten the values into the key Name.

So instead of getting a consistent Key named 'Signers' to reference I instead get key = 'Signers FIRSTNAME LASTNAME' which varies each instance of the zap and causes it to break.

I only need the email that is stored in this section to be able to lookup their account via our CRM but can't get it to run consistently because of this key naming issue. Is there some way I can parse through the raw response data of this trigger?

[Screenshot of Response Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8l0r.jpg)

[Screenshot of Zapier Object with Flattened Key Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeEbY.jpg)

Comment: This looks to be an issue with the SignNow integration itself. I'd reach out to Zapier support (http://zapier.com/contact) and they'll be able to log a request into the SignNow team. I don't believe this is something you can fix on your own.